# how to pass a int array value to another class in java

Tags: java

I am having three class one is linklist class and a LinkLLiat1 class and a LinkList2 class.can any one please help me to pass the getStudentID value to linklist class.

This is the LinkList1  class

```
   public class LinkList1 
    {
       public LinkList1 next;

       private int EmployeeID;
       private String EmployeeName;
       private String EmpContactNo;
       private String DOB;
       private String DateofJoined;
       private String DepatmentName;  


       public LinkList1 (int Employeeid, String Employeename, String EmpContactno, String dob, String Dateofjoined, String Depatmentname)
       {

           EmployeeID=Employeeid; // initialized class variable
           EmployeeName=Employeename; // initialized class variable
           EmpContactNo=EmpContactno; // initialized class variable
           DOB=dob; // initialized class variable
           DateofJoined=Dateofjoined; // initialized class variable
           DepatmentName=Depatmentname; // initialized class variable
       }
       public void DisplayLink()
       {
           System.out.println("("+EmployeeID+","+EmployeeName+","+EmpContactNo+","+DOB
                   +","+DateofJoined+","+DepatmentName.toUpperCase()+")");
       }
            public int getStudentID()
       {
           return EmployeeID;
       }
    }
```

this is in the LinkList2..

```
public class LinkList2 
{
    private LinkList1 first; // refer tp first link on the list
       public LinkList2 () // constructor
       {
           first = null; // no items on list yet
       }
       public boolean empty()
       {
           return (first==null);
       }
       public void insert(int Employeeid, String Employeename, String EmpContactno, String dob, String Dateofjoined, String Depatmentname)
       {
           LinkList1 newLinkList1= new LinkList1(Employeeid, Employeename, EmpContactno, dob, Dateofjoined, Depatmentname);
           newLinkList1.next= first; // newlink --> old first
           first = newLinkList1; // first --> new link

       }

       public LinkList1 delete() // elete first item
       {
           LinkList1 tem=first; //save reference to link
           first = first.next; //selete it: first--> old next
           return tem; // return deleted link
       }
  public int[] myListStudent(LinkList2 thelist)
  {
      int myStudentNo[]=new int[5];
       LinkList1 current = first;
       int i=0;
        while (thelist!=null) // until end of list
           {
            int a=current.getStudentID();
               myStudentNo[i]=current.getStudentID();
               current = current.next; //move to next link
           }

      return myStudentNo;

  }
       public void displaylist()
       {
           System.out.println(" ID, Name, Contact No" + 
                   "Date of Birth. Date of Joined, Work Department ID");
           LinkList1 current = first; // start at beginning of list
           while (current!=null) // until end of list
           {
               current.DisplayLink(); //print data
               current = current.next; //move to next link
           }
           System.out.println("");
           }



}
```

i need to get the getStudentID values from the above class to the myArray in which is in mainlinklist class..

```
    public class LinkList 
{




    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        LinkList2 thelist = new LinkList2(); // make new list

        thelist.insert(1, "ssd", "071123456", "9.10.1993", "10.11.2010", "HR");
        thelist.insert(12, "dcfs", "071123456", "9.10.1993", "10.11.2010", "ACC");

        thelist.displaylist();

         LinkList2 myStudent = new LinkList2();
         int myArray[];
         myArray=myStudent.myListStudent(thelist);
        while(!thelist.empty())
        {
            LinkList1 aLink = thelist.delete();
            System.out.println("Deleted");
            aLink.DisplayLink();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("");  
        }


    }


}
```

what i want to do is get the EmployeeID vlues in LinkList1 to LinkList2 and the to Linklist.. i want to collect the values  EmployeeID .. i don't know many be i am doing to totally wrong .. :) which means from this myStudentNo in below to the MyArray in linklist..

```
 public int[] myListStudent(LinkList2 thelist)
      {
          int myStudentNo[]=new int[5];
           LinkList1 current = first;
           int i=0;
            while (thelist!=null) // until end of list
               {
                int a=current.getStudentID();
                   myStudentNo[i]=current.getStudentID();
                   current = current.next; //move to next link
               }

          return myStudentNo;

      }
```

Comment: can you explain what you try to do in LinkList1 class? what is purpose of LinkList1?why do not you combine LinkList1 and LinkList2 together? is LinkList1 supper class of LinkList2? –  Kick Buttowski

Comment: linklist is the main class and LinkList is the node where i am getting values from the main and LinkList 2 i use to to the oerations like delete and add .. and iam using Netbeans and as this is an assginmnet i need to have three different classes :( and now i have to get the vlaues of myListStudent to the  main class .. so i can get the values to do a search of The IDs in the linklist ..

Comment: please explain the usage of** LinkList1** class? Is your specification forced you to use 3 different classes? To me, you can combine LinkList1 and LinkList2 together to simplify your situation?

Comment: ya specification is like that need to have three class :( LinkList1 has the variables to collect the data that i put to linklist "main" class

Comment: Is it possible to post up the specification?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass it through the constructor.

Eg. when you create an instance of the class do

```
CLASS name = new CLASS(variableToPass);
```

UPDATE:

When you create an instance of the class that you wish to pass it to, use the variable as an argument of the constructor of that class. I hope it is easier to understand now.

When you create a new instance of a class the constructor is called.

This is an example of a constructor:

```
public ClassName() {
}
```

This constructor takes no arguments and therefore creating an instance of that class is as follows:

```
ClassName class = new ClassName();
```

Constructors can also take arguments and set them to values:

```
int i = 0;

public ClassName(int i){
this.i = i;
}

ClassName class = new ClassName(1);
```

This would set the instance variable of i to the value of i given. this. refers to the instance variable.

You should add what you want to pass through the constructor this way.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: I don't understand how this doesn't attempt to answer the question. I edited it to show an example of what I meant. I'm not going to write all of his code for him.

Comment: at least, can you explain your answer in better way?

Comment: Is this any better? Sorry for not answering it well enough.

Comment: @JakeArnold Yes, it's better. To mods: Please disregard my flag.

Comment: do not worry. we just try to understand your answer better. To me, the question has some missing info and kind of not clear

Comment: Thanks hex. I think that is a lot more comprehensive now.

Comment: Thanks :)  actually i am v new to java.. did you mean to add the variableToPass in this ...                                       ListEmployeeList TheEmNo = new ListEmployeeList ();                        sorry i couldnt understand much can u plz explain bit more :) thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot Jake :) for trying to help me .. but still it is getting errors.. ill edit the question in detail :)